# Why does swift provide both a CGRect initializer and a CGRectMake function?

Tags: swift, function, design-patterns, constructor

When I was learning about Core Graphics in swift, the tutorials that I watched on youtube use the `CGRectMake` function instead of the initializer of `CGRect` to create a `CGRect` instance.

This is so weird to me. I don't understand why should I use the former because the parameters are the same and I think there is no performance benefit to using the `XXXMake` function.

Also, why does swift even have such a "Make" function, when `CGRect` already has an initializer with exactly the same parameters? I think the developers of the modules is using a certain design pattern that I don't know. Did they use one? If yes, what is it? I really want to know some more design patterns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Short answer:* `CGRectMake` is not "provided by Swift". The corresponding C function in the CoreGraphics
framework is automatically imported and therefore available in Swift.

*Longer answer:*
[CGRectMake](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455245-cgrectmake) is defined in 
"CGGeometry.h" from the CoreGraphics framework as

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

In (Objective-)C, that function provides a convenient way to
initialize a `CGRect` variable:

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(x, y, h, w);
```

The Swift compiler *automatically imports* all functions from the
Foundation header files (if they are Swift-compatible), so this
is imported as

```
public func CGRectMake(x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect
```

You can either use that one, or one of the Swift initializers

```
public init(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize)
public init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
public init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double)
public init(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int)
```

I don't think that it makes any performance difference. Many people might
use `CGRectMake()` because they are used to it from the old pre-Swift
times. The Swift initializers are more "swifty" and more expressive with
the explicit argument labels:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: x, width: w, height: h)
```

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 3/Xcode 8,** `CGRectMake` is no longer
available in Swift.