# What's the difference between using CGSizeMake and CGSize? Is one better than the other?

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat, cgsize

`CGSize(width: 360, height: 480)` and `CGSizeMake(360, 480)` seem to have the same effect. Is one preferred to the other? What is the difference?

Comment: Similar: [Why does swift provide both a CGRect initializer and a CGRectMake function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717650/why-does-swift-provide-both-a-cgrect-initializer-and-a-cgrectmake-function).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CGSize` constructor is a Swift extension on `CGSize`:

```
extension CGSize {
    public static var zero: CGSize { get }
    public init(width: Int, height: Int)
    public init(width: Double, height: Double)
}
```

`CGSizeMake` is a leftover inline function bridged from Objective-C:

```
/*** Definitions of inline functions. ***/

// ...

public func CGSizeMake(width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGSize
```

Both have the same functionality in Swift, the `CGSize` constructor is just more "Swifty" than the other and provided as a convenience.

Comment: So is one preferred over the other? Thanks!

Comment: It's all preference, although I've found that working with a pure Swift codebase `CGSize(...)` is cleaner than `CGSizeMake(...)`.

Comment: Cool thanks @JAL! Unfortunately must wait 9 min to accept your answer :)

Comment: @Crashalot Sure, I'll take a look at those as I have time this week.  Happy hacking!

Comment: I'm curious about how this works out with swift. From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake "your applications should avoid directly reading and writing the data stored in the CGRect data structure. Instead, use the functions described here to manipulate rectangles and to retrieve their characteristics.". Talking about functions like `CGRectGetMidX` `CGRectGetWidth` and the like.

Comment: @AndrewCarter Those inline `CGRectGet[X]` functions should still work the same way in Swift, although I'm not really sure if that's what you're asking.  If that's not what you're asking, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I'm wondering if Apple's recommendation to not directly access the data in the CGRect is still valid. Maybe I will ask a new question :)

Comment: @AndrewCarter Ah, I see what you're asking now.  Please ask a new question and I will definitely answer it!

Comment: @AndrewCarter (and anyone else who is curious): I've attempt to answer any questions about `CGRect` normalization in Swift here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35608638/2415822

Answer (score 2):

While as functionality they don't have any difference, `CGSizeMake()` is/will be deprecated. It is easier to write and read `CGSize()`, so Apple prefers you to use `CGSize()` for the future.

Comment: "CGSizeMake() is/will be depreciated" can you back this claim up with a creditable source?

Comment: I haven't seen them included in the latest apple swift and foundation repos

Comment: FYI - you mean "deprecated", not "depreciated". Very different meanings. :)

Answer (score 1):

So in case if you are talking about the difference on usability aspect then there is no basic difference between `CGSize()` and `CGSizeMake()`.

But if you are talking about structural and programatic difference between this twos then here is some code snippet structure and explanation as well.

1. `CGSize()`

   ```
   struct CGSize { var width: CGFloat var height: CGFloat init() init(width width: CGFloat, height height: CGFloat) }
   ```
2. `CGSizeMake()`

   ```
   func CGSizeMake(_ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGSize
   ```

**Explanation**:-

On the first case here i.e. `CGSize()`, the code clearly demonstrates that its a structure which generally takes height and width as `CGFloat()`and represent a distance vector but not a physical size. As a vector the value could be negative.

On another hand in case of `CGSizeMake()`, we can easily understand that its a function rather than a structure. It generally takes height and width as `CGFloat()`and returns a `CGSize()` structure.

**Example**:-

1. `CGSize()`

   ```
   var sizeValue = CGSize(width: 20, height: 30) //Taking Width and Height
   ```
2. `CGSizeMake()`

   ```
   var sizeValue = CGSizeMake(20,30) //Taking Width and Height too but without named parameters
   ```

Now in case of pure swift usage and code `CGSize()` is much simpler and understandable than `CGSizeMake()`. You can get that from the above example right..!!!!

Thanks,

Hope This Helped.