# Accessing CGRect values directly vs normalizing them in Swift - Objective-C rules still valid?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgrect

This question is inspired by [Andrew Carter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981995/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgsizemake-and-cgsize-is-one-better-than-th/34982029#comment57724793_34982029) on a previous question about the new `CGSize` initializer in Swift.

The [Apple Docs for CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/) say:

> ... your applications
>   should avoid directly reading and writing the data stored in the
>   CGRect data structure. Instead, use the functions described here to
>   manipulate rectangles and to retrieve their characteristics.

Is Apple's recommendation to not directly access the data in a `CGRect` still valid with Swift?  Why should `CGRectGetMidX`, `CGRectGetWidth`, etc. be used in place of accessing the values of a `CGRect` struct directly, when these properties are now exposed with Swift's new extension on `CGRect`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a non-standard `CGRect` with a negative width and height:

```
var rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: -10.0, height: -10.0)
```

This is a valid rectangle according to the Apple docs, as "a rectangle with an origin of `[0.0, 0.0]` and a size of `[10.0, 10.0]` is exactly equivalent to a rectangle with an origin of `[10.0, 10.0]` and a size of `[-10.0, -10.0]`."

You can standardize this `CGRect` by calling the legacy inline `CGRectStandardize` method like in Objective-C, or any of the new methods provided on the Swift extension of `CGRect`:

```
CGRectStandardize(rect) // {x -10 y -10 w 10 h 10}
rect.standardized // {x -10 y -10 w 10 h 10}
rect.standardizeInPlace() // {x -10 y -10 w 10 h 10}
```

**But wait!**  This will reposition your rect on the coordinate plane, not only making your width and height positive, but making your `origin` negative to reflect the initial position of the rect with its negative width and height.

The inline `CGRectGet` functions provide an interface to normalize a specific value of your rect, without changing its origin.  Swift provides an extension on `CGRect` so you can access the normalized values directly, rather than using the legacy C methods provided by `CGGeometry`:

```
var rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: -10.0, height: -10.0)

rect.size.width // non-normalized, returns -10
CGRectGetWidth(rect) // bridged C function, normalized, returns 10
rect.width // new from Swift extension on CGRect, normalized, returns 10
```

The new interfaces:

```
extension CGRect {
    // ...
    public var width: CGFloat { get }
    public var height: CGFloat { get }
    public var minX: CGFloat { get }
    public var midX: CGFloat { get }
    public var maxX: CGFloat { get }
    public var minY: CGFloat { get }
    public var midY: CGFloat { get }
    public var maxY: CGFloat { get }
    // ...
}
```

So the answer is yes, the same rules for `CGRect` in Objective-C apply in Swift as well.  The only difference here is that Swift provides an extension on some `CGGeometry` structs which allow you to move away from the old inline C functions bridged from the `CGGeometry` headers.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, it looks like `CGRectGetWidth()` is replaced by `CGRect.width`.

[image]