# How to set size of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm following some online examples I found on how to setup a UI Scroll View and have run into a problem with setting the size of the Scroll View. I'm attempting to set the size to height = height of screen and width = 3x width of screen. Here is the code I'm attempting, but CGSizeMake is no longer supported in Swift3. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this without CGSizeMake?

```
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there CGSize(...) instead of CGSizeMake() ?

Comment: use CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGSizeMake` is deprecated in Swift 3. Use regular`CGSize` instead. Your code should look like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

The <s>main</s> only difference between them is that you have to type in the parameter names (width, and height) for `CGSize`, while you do not need to for `CGSizeMake`.

You can take a look at this question for additional information: [What's the difference between using CGSizeMake and CGSize? Is one better than the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981995/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgsizemake-and-cgsize-is-one-better-than-th)

Simply put, `CGSize`, is used more commonly in Swift because it's considered more "Swifty". `CGSizeMake` is a leftover from Objective-C