# What is the main difference between SCNVector3 and SCNVector3Make

Tags: ios, swift, vector, scenekit

I read the Apple's documentation about both classes but I am not quite sure when and when not to use which one?
Since SCNVector3's constructor(s) also accept same parameters and return the same thing that's so confusing to have a method named SCNVector3Make

Comment: Related: [Why does swift provide both a CGRect initializer and a CGRectMake function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717650/why-does-swift-provide-both-a-cgrect-initializer-and-a-cgrectmake-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SCNVector3Make` is a convenience function, it is not a class.

`SCNVector3` is a `struct`, not a `class`.

Either works if your x, y, and z values are `Float`.

```
let vector = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
```

or:

```
let vector = SCNVectorMake(x, y, z)
```

Both give you a `SCNVector3` initialized with the 3 `Float` values.

If your values are other types (`Int`, `Double`, `CGFloat`), use the associated `SCNVector3` initializer since `SCNVector3Make` only works with `Float`.

Comment: Yup. Historical / cross-language perspective: in (Obj)C, structs traditionally don't have initializers like classes do, so Make functions are provided as a convenience for creating and populating a struct. (Yes, more recent C compilers have added struct initializer syntax. But that looks weird. And many of these functions were created before then.) In Swift the struct automatically gets a member-wise initializer, and Apple defined a few other initializers for ease of passing in other value types. The Make function imports to Swift just like any C function, but it's sort of vestigial there.